# Postgres is stuck in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql, recovery

I have a stand-alone instance of PostgreSQL which is in recovery mode. It has been saying

```
2014-03-24 18:45:57 MDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

For many hours, and `ps` shows:

```
postgres  2637  0.1  0.1 116916  4420 ?        Ds   15:43   0:18 postgres: startup process   recovering 00000001000000040000007E
```

Is there any way to watch the progress of the recovery, ideally with an ETA? How can I get this process "un-stuck"?

I can stop postgres using the standard start/stop scripts, but when I start it again, it's still stuck in recovery mode.

Debian 7.4, Linux kernel 3.2.0, PostgreSQL 9.1.12

---

Output of `strace -p 2637`:

```
Process 2637 attached - interrupt to quit
close(154)                              = 0
getppid()                               = 2600
open("pg_clog/0003", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = 154
lseek(154, 221184, SEEK_SET)            = 221184
write(154, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
fsync(154)                              = 0
```

The above output repeats seemingly infinitely.

---

A gdb backtrace (three subsequent bts were all practically identical):

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f0c8f917d70 in fsync () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f0c9169f255 in pg_fsync_no_writethrough (fd=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/storage/file/fd.c:286
#2  0x00007f0c9169f265 in pg_fsync (fd=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/storage/file/fd.c:274
#3  0x00007f0c9151917b in SlruPhysicalWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f0c91b856c0, pageno=pageno@entry=123, slotno=slotno@entry=3, fdata=fdata@entry=0x0) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1- 9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:801
#4  0x00007f0c91519925 in SlruInternalWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f0c91b856c0, slotno=3, fdata=fdata@entry=0x0) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:528
#5  0x00007f0c9151a1c7 in SimpleLruWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f0c91b856c0, slotno=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:565
#6  0x00007f0c915018e3 in clog_redo (lsn=..., record=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/clog.c:720
#7  0x00007f0c91515f08 in StartupXLOG () at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c:6664
#8  0x00007f0c91518537 in StartupProcessMain () at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c:10179
#9  0x00007f0c9152f1ba in AuxiliaryProcessMain (argc=<optimized out>, argc@entry=2, argv=<optimized out>, argv@entry=0x7fff651b0610) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/bootstrap/bootstrap.c:409
#10 0x00007f0c9167ddeb in StartChildProcess (type=StartupProcess) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4512
#11 0x00007f0c916806ac in PostmasterMain (argc=argc@entry=5, argv=argv@entry=0x7f0c91d8e180) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1118
#12 0x00007f0c914d392f in main (argc=5, argv=0x7f0c91d8e180) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/main/main.c:209
```

And if I set:

```
fsync = off
```

And run the bt again:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3d99ab7160 in write () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3d9b6be0c6 in SlruPhysicalWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f3d9bd2a6c0, pageno=pageno@entry=123, slotno=slotno@entry=3, fdata=fdata@entry=0x0) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:783
#2  0x00007f3d9b6be925 in SlruInternalWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f3d9bd2a6c0, slotno=3, fdata=fdata@entry=0x0) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:528
#3  0x00007f3d9b6bf1c7 in SimpleLruWritePage (ctl=ctl@entry=0x7f3d9bd2a6c0, slotno=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/slru.c:565
#4  0x00007f3d9b6a68e3 in clog_redo (lsn=..., record=<optimized out>) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/clog.c:720
#5  0x00007f3d9b6baf08 in StartupXLOG () at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c:6664
#6  0x00007f3d9b6bd537 in StartupProcessMain () at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c:10179
#7  0x00007f3d9b6d41ba in AuxiliaryProcessMain (argc=<optimized out>, argc@entry=2, argv=<optimized out>, argv@entry=0x7fff99d477a0) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/bootstrap/bootstrap.c:409
#8  0x00007f3d9b822deb in StartChildProcess (type=StartupProcess) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4512
#9  0x00007f3d9b8256ac in PostmasterMain (argc=argc@entry=5, argv=argv@entry=0x7f3d9d614180) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1118
#10 0x00007f3d9b67892f in main (argc=5, argv=0x7f3d9d614180) at /home/cbe/projects/postgresql/9.1/postgresql-9.1-9.1.12/build/../src/backend/main/main.c:209
```

Comment: Does the recovery position change? If not, are you sure this isn't actually a warm standby server? Is there a `recovery.conf` in the PostgreSQL data directory?

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`? Is it using CPU? If you `sudo strace -p 2637` does it show any kind of activity? What PostgreSQL version and operating system?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Question updated with versions and strace output. dmesg shows nothing of interest.  top shows one CPU core being 100% consumed by `wait`, but the postgres process itself using very little CPU (occasionally spiking to about 3%, usually well below 1%).

Comment: OK, something looks broken here. If you terminate PostgreSQL then restart it does anything change? Consider installing the -dbg packages for this postgresql release, attaching gdb, and getting a couple of backtraces to see what it thinks it's working on; see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD

Comment: @CraigRinger: Question updated with backtrace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After googling for hours, I stumbled across [a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.databases.postgresql.hackers/yXyFP2QLmsE/NK8fPowq7FEJ) that wasn't really related to my issue, best I could tell, but it seemed harmless enough to try, and *voilà!*

I looked at `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_clog`, and saw:

```
drwx------  2 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 15 15:20 .
drwx------ 13 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 25 12:15 ..
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 262144 Feb  4 19:39 0000
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 262144 Feb 13 11:10 0001
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 262144 Mar 15 15:20 0002
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 229376 Mar 25 14:51 0003
```

Noticing that `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_clog/0003` was the file being opened/seeked in the `strace` output, and that this was the file in question in the forum post, I tried the suggested action in the forum:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=8k count=1 >> /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_clog/0003
```

And now postgres starts again.